Modals verbs used to show permission

You may ask questions later.

You could ask questions later.


#1 gives permission. What about #2? It shows a certain degree of likelihood and nothing more? Does "could" only show permission while asking a question for instance "Could you open the window"? "Yes I could or no I couldn't". But without that question it just shows possibility. Am I right?

Daba, please check your spelling. Are you using a smartphone for this. could is a possibility here.  You could ask questions later [if you want to.] The if clause is implied in these cases.

I use smartphone. Sorry for mistakes. So both 1 and 2 show permission?

May I ask questions? Yes, you may. Here, could is possibility. Could I ask questions [if possible]. Could you open the window [if you don't mind]? It is not strictly speaking permission. It is asking somebody to do something for you.

Don't forget the main reason #1 is likely (not definitely) to be a reference to permission is because it's addressed to you (and obviously you'd know better than the speaker whether you were likely to ask questions, so why would he say that?). If it was John may ask questions later, I'd assume by default it just meant it was possible (but not necessarily likely) that John might ask questions. It's more a matter of logical context than the difference between may, might, can, could.

Modal verbs - May and could.
OP had asked how these modal verbs are used (meaning)


You may ask questions later.
#1 gives permission


May is used for
• Permission/ Request.
• Possibility.
• More formal.
• Prayer
May = request/ permission :- The term later appears in the sentence. Thus, the listeners are being requested to submit queries not now but later.


You could ask questions later.
What about #2? It shows a certain degree of likelihood and nothing more?


Could  is used to show
• Ability in the past.
• Possibility.
• Permission.
• Suggestion.
• Polite request
Could = Polite request/ permission:-      Once more, the phrase later indicates that the audience is being requested politely to submit their questions at a later time.


Does "could" only show permission while asking a question for instance
"Could you open the window"?
"Yes I could or no I couldn't". But without that question it just shows possibility. Am I right?


Could = Polite request :-
In this case, could does not imply whether the listener has the ability of opening the window. It's more of a polite request.

May, could and can are all used in some way to ask permission or make a request.
May is extremely formal. It would be very unusual to hear it in conversations among friends and acquaintances. It's also used very differently from could and can because it's much more of an order or a definitive answer than a request. I'll show in an example below.
Could and can are much more commonly used to make requests. Could is just slightly more formal than can. Because of that, could leans closer to being a request, and can leans closer to being an order.

(1) Could you open that window for me?
(2) Can you grab that sweater out of the closet?

In (1), there's still a very, very small bit of doubt that you will say "No" and you won't open the window. In (2), it's pretty much assumed that you will get the sweater out of the closet for me. (of course, context is everything)
May can't be used in the same way. You can use it to tell someone what they can do (declarative sentence), but not to ask them to do something for you. When you use it in a question, you are most commonly asking permission for yourself. For example:

May I have another, please?
Yes, you may have another.

While can is used for informal requests, it's also used to indicate ability. When someone is being overly polite and asks permission for something that they really don't need to ask permission for, there's a fairly common joke that's a play on the meaning of can. For example, I might ask my friend:
"Can I open this last can of Pringles?" And he replies, "I don't know, can you?"
Can was clearly used as a request but my friend is pretending to interpret it as a question of ability to imply that it was an unnecessary request. I only mention it because it's a fairly common joke.

As a child in England in the 1960's we had a teacher who was very strict about the difference between "can" and "may".   CHILD: Please Sir, can I go to the toilet?   TEACHER: Yes, you can.   TEACHER: Sit down.  I didn't say you may, I said you can.  (i.e. you have the ability to go to the toilet, but I haven't given you my permission).   After this had happened to various classmates, we soon knew the difference between can and may.

But to answer the original question, "Can I?" to ask permission is acceptable colloquial use of language these days, especially if someone says to me "Can I get you a drink?"

Oh yes, absolutely! I would say not only acceptable, but also the most common colloquial use.

@RuthMcT. What is the reason the teacher insisted on "may" instead of "can ? Is it more polite? We were taught like that. But no one seems to agree on ELL. It is mentioned in Cambridge dictionary.
May I get in?

@James Mathai.  It's related to the point swmcdonnell made at the end of their answer above.  Our teacher was insistent that "can" should only be used for "have the ability to", and "may" for the request to "have permission to".  Of course he could have been having a joke at the expense of a class of nine-year-olds, but if so I didn't get the joke.

@RuthMcT According to Cambridge dictionary - Asking for permission Can I ask you a question? = informal Could I use your phone ? = more formal/polite May I use your phone = even more formal/polite. Giving permission Yes, you can.= informal Yes, you may.= formal/polite

@JamesMathai  Remember that I was quoting from my experience 50-60 years ago. Language changes, and seems to me usually to do so in the direction from more to less formal.  Please note my second comment in this thread, which you have confirmed by the entry in the Cambridge dictionary.

@RuthMcT We are still following that grammar and Cambridge dictionary doesn't say that it is out of fashion. Also I saw a letter to the Principal with the salutation: "Dear Sir" instead of "Respected Sir" in a UK publisher's text book. Has it changed?

@JamesMathai Respected Sir is never used these days; it is always Dear Sir.
